# Byte downloading via torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

Is that possible to download only several bytes using torrents? E.g. download all ID2 headers from all mp3 files in torrent.

Comment: Possible, yes, but I'm not aware of any client that is set up to do this. Suggest move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

but you can write script which downloads only pieces which contain part of file which contain desired data and process that piece(partOFfile). but its very complex process. size of pieces relies on size of torrent so you can end up downloading whole song if torrent is big. it depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

No , there is no such facility in existing torrent clients , you should build your Torrent client to do that .